# Add /usr/local/sbin to the PATH of a user

Tags: bash, debian, path

if I type

```
echo $PATH
```

I only get

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

how can I add `/usr/local/sbin` to the path, so it is already there the next time?

(I use debian squeeze)

Comment: See here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/310817/198133

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The easiest way is to add this line to your user's `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin
```

Bear in mind that `/sbin/`, `/usr/sbin` and `/usr/local/sbin` are not in normal users' $PATHs by default because these directories tend to contain "dangerous" executables. Things like `fdisk` or `deluser` that need administrative privileges and can harm your computer. They should be in `root`'s path by default and you need to be `root` to run them anyway, so it migh be a good idea not to add them to a normal user's $PATH.

Comment: Assuming they are using bash.

Comment: @vgoff the question is tagged with [tag:bash].

Comment: Yes, it is.  Didn't notice initially.  Left it after I hit 'add comment'

Comment: Wouldnt that add the path to $PATH again and again? And which would be the correct path to store own written bash files then? files, that the user may execute?

Comment: @rubo77 The PATH is only set for a shell session, and `.bashrc` is only called once at the start of the session. Your own scripts, you could store them in `~/bin`, and add that to the path, for example.

Comment: @rubo77 No, `PATH=$PATH:/foo` _appends_ `/foo` to the current value of `$PATH`. `PATH=/foo:$PATH` _prepends_ `/foo` to the current value of `$PATH`. As for where you place your own scripts, the most common is `~/bin` but you can use whatever you like as long as you add it to your $PATH as described. Personally I use `~/scripts`.

Comment: OK. but isn't there a convention where to store text-bash files that all users may execute? I created a new question about that: http://superuser.com/questions/595828/where-to-store-text-bash-files-that-all-users-may-execute-on-debian

Comment: @rubo77 you may be thinking of `/usr/local/bin` as `/usr/bin` is generally used by the 'OS vendor'.  This means that if you do updates, and your script happens to have a name of some new inclusion, it will be over-written.

Comment: Do you recommend adding to the start (as in @criziot's answer) or end of the path (as in your answer)? Why?

Comment: @drevicko if you add the new dir to the beginning, executables in it will take precedence. If you have two executables named `foo`,  the one that was found first, so the one in the directory of your PATH that comes first, will be executed when you run `foo`. So it's up to you. If you want the new dir to take precedence, add it to the beginning, otherwise, add it to the end.

Comment: @terdon doesn't really answer my question, but sbin is intended for executables that require admin preveliges and bin for those for everyone, so you'd not expect the same executable in both. That means it's probably not an issue which is first. It's usually safer to put things at the end of the path though, unless you've a good reason not to.

Comment: @drevicko no, the only difference is precedence. For example, I like having the directory holding my own programs first, since I sometimes write wrapper scripts to replace the standard tools.

Comment: @terdon yes, but a less experienced user can get into trouble with that - if some program they run from the terminal expects certain behaviours from standard tools which are different in the folder added to the front of PATH, they may break. An example is running anaconda python (which adds itself to the front of PATH) and then using `brew` on a mac. Other examples can come from version conflicts in standard tools.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following to the end of the `.bashrc` of the user:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
```