# Where to store bash scripts that all users may execute on Debian?

Tags: bash, debian, path

I have many bash scripts on my server, that all users may use.

but it seems the location

```
/usr/local/sbin
```

is not the best place.

I don't want to use the home directory of the users, cause everybody may execute them.

is there a convention about where to store them on Debian?

Comment: `/usr/local/bin` is the usual place for this

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "official" place for local executables is `/usr/local/bin`. This directory is usually in the $PATH of all users by default. Traditionally, programs that are not installed through a package manager (eg `apt`) are stored in the `/usr/local/bin` directory and those installed by the package manager in `/usr/bin`. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8658/22222) for some more information and [here](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html) for the official definitions and more details than you will ever need.

These are just conventions though and you are free to use your own directory. For example, to store scripts that can be executed by all users in `/usr/local/scripts` you would need to follow these steps:

1. Create the directory (I am assuming you have `sudo` configured, if not just switch to `root` with `su`) and allow execution:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /usr/local/scripts
   sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/scripts
   ```
2. Add this directory to all user's $PATHs (this assumes everyone is using bash). Add this line to `/etc/profile`:

   ```
   export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/scripts
   ```

A better way (as [@Michał Šrajer](https://superuser.com/users/76747/michal-srajer) pointed out in the comments) that will work for most shells (at least any that use the [`pam_env`](http://linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_env.html) module would be to set the $PATH in `/etc/environment`. For example:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/scripts"
```

Comment: In debian `PATH` is set globally in `/etc/environment`. 
BTW, since Squeeze, Bash is no longer default shell. Dash is.

Comment: I wonder why I should store a plain-text script in a folder called "bin" or "sbin"? Aren't "binaries" compiled files, that are non-text?

Comment: Strictly speaking yes, that is what binaries are. However, by convention all executables are stored in the various `bin` directories. For example, on my system, `/usr/bin` contains 2061 compiled binary files and 3888 scripts (text files).